# how to change the datatype varchar(50) to datetime datatype in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currently working with an existing table and I want to change the data type of an existing column.

I have a `VARCHAR` "Travel Date" column. Now I want to change the data type to `DATETIME`.

```
TravelDate
----------
27/02/2014
27/02/2014
27/02/2014
26/02/2014
27/02/2014
26/02/2014
27/02/2014
27/02/2014
27/02/2014
27/02/2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your string with appropriate style(http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/04/list-of-all-available-datetime-format.html). Then Alter your column.

```
UPDATE TableName SET TravelDate =  CONVERT(DATETIME, TravelDate, 103)

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ALTER COLUMN TravelDate DATETIME NULL[NOT NULL]
GO
```